# UpperCase only first two letters of all filenames in a folder?

Tags: powershell

I know I can convert all filenames in a given folder to uppercase with the following:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path your_path -Recurse | Rename-item -NewName {$_.name.ToUpper()}
```

However, how can I capitalize only the first two letters of all filenames in a folder?

i.e.

**ls**123456_This_is_a_Test.pdf --> **LS**123456_This_is_a_Test.pdf

**re**98765_Another_Test.pdf --> **RE**98765_Another_Test.pdf

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `.SubString()` method to separate the first two characters

```
## Q:\Test\2018\07\21\SO_51451148.ps1
$Folder = (Get-Item '.').FullName
Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -File -Recurse |
 Where-Object Name -match '^[a-z]{2}.' |
   Rename-item -NewName {"{0}{1}" -f $_.Name.SubString(0,2).ToUpper(),
                                     $_.Name.Substring(2)} -WhatIf
```

If the output looks OK, remove the `-WhatIf` parameter

Comment: Add -file to gci , otherwise you rename directory too, and test if name have a length great or equal to 2 otherwise you can have error

Comment: @Esperento57 Good hints, incorporated them.

Comment: my vote then  (evn if your correction dont take file with only one caracter :P )

Answer (score 1):

try it :

```
Get-ChildItem "c:\temp" -file  | %{

    if ($_.Name.Length -gt 1)
    {
        $NewName="{0}{1}" -f $_.Name.SubString(0, 2).ToUpper(), $_.Name.Substring(2)
    }
    else
    {
        $NewName=$_.Name.ToUpper()
    }

    Rename-item $_.FullName $NewName -WhatIf

}
```